# pass custom parameters to ajax request and get back the same in response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make a series of asynchronous AJAX calls and the response is dumped into a textfile. Now if I want to identify the responses got from all those AJAX calls in that file, I don't have a unique identifier. So is there a way to send a custom parameter in the AJAX call and get the same on response so that the call made will be unique to that AJAX request?

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl, // Location of the service
    data: postData, //Data sent to server
    contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
    crossDomain: true,
    async: true,
    password : attr,
    success: function(data,success) {
             }
   });
```

Comment: use specific response handler for each call

Comment: Show us the piece of code you have written so far. It would be easier for us to help you that way.

Comment: wrap the whole AJAX call in a function which takes your custom parameter as an argument - then it'll still be available when the response comes

Comment: Can i get an example code snippet since im relatively new to ajax calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using your code snippet above, without moving it to it's own function, you can do something like this

```
...
...
inputIdentifer = 'this is some sort of identifying value';
(function(identifier) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postUrl, // Location of the service
        data: postData, //Data sent to server
        contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        password: attr,
        success: function(data, success) {
            console.log(identifier);
        }
    });
}(inputIdentifier));
...
...
```

you'll see that the success function has the identifier

Answer (score 3):

You can add to the object, like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: postUrl, // Location of the service
data: postData, //Data sent to server
contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
crossDomain: true,
async: true,
password: attr,
anyPropName: "this your data",
success: function (data, success) {
    console.log(this.anyNameHere);
}
```

});

When you call **this** in the success function, you will get the object that you already defined for ajax. $.ajax(**{...}**);.